# Returning results of a MySQL GROUP BY query as columns

Tags: mysql, nested

I'm sure this question has been asked, but I can't quite figure out what to Google.

I have a big database of beer purchases listed by order date and type, like so:

```
order_date | beer_type
-----------
2014-01-04 | amber
2014-01-05 | lager
2014-04-01 | amber
```

There are 1.4 million records, and I want to get them into a table with the month of the purchase as rows and the quantity of each type purchases as columns:

```
month | amber | lager | wheat
-----------------------------
1     | 2092  | 3030  | 990
2     | 1890  | 2025  | 1028
```

I have no trouble with the actual grouping:

```
SELECT beer_type, MONTH(order_date) AS month, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM purchases
GROUP BY month,beer_type 
ORDER BY month,beer_type ASC
```

But of course, that still gives me a long two-column table which I then have to nest myself. But I don't want to write a query in which I have to manually enter all the beer_types. There must be an easy way to nest results like this?

Comment: Look into group_concat https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: You need to define a 'pivot' table. 

Possible duplicate 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table'.

Comment: Looks like "Pivot" was the word I needed for search. Will read other questions. Thx!